# A WindowsFormsHost cannot be rotated. To suppress this error, handle the LayoutError event and set ThrowException to false

Tags: .net, xaml, vlc, windowsformshost

I have VLC ActiveX Plugin control inside of WPF.

```
<Grid> 
    <WindowsFormsHost  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" Visibility="Hidden"   Name="windowsFormsHost1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ClipToBounds="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"  /> 
 </Grid>
```

And when I try to apply some animation I am facing this error:

```
A WindowsFormsHost cannot be rotated. To suppress this error, handle the LayoutError event and set ThrowException to false.
```

Any clue how we can fix it?

Comment: From the error it would appear that you can't animate embedded winforms controls.  To fix it, don't use winforms controls.

Comment: @mydogisbox Yeah... But it means that I have drop down VLC ActiveX Plugin as well and buy something else that done in WPF.

Comment: That is unfortunate, but the error message seems pretty clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is pretty straight forward.  You simply can't rotate or resize `WinFormsHost` controls.  See [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/surfaceappdevelopment/thread/a3eed1a5-3895-4a83-bdd2-6d5caf47db0c/).