# c# WPF video rotation inside picturebox

Tags: c#, wpf, rotation, picturebox

I hosted a picturebox inside a WPF window inside a stackpanel. I put code to rotate the stackpanel but it doesn't also rotate its child elements, why? I want it to rotate the video stream inside the picturebox during runtime when clicking the rotate button. how do i do it?

```
private void rotate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RotateTransform rotateTransform = new RotateTransform(45);
    panel.RenderTransform = rotateTransform;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't rotate Windows Forms controls so you will need to replace the `WindowsFormHost` with a WPF control to be able to rotate it:

[A WindowsFormsHost cannot be rotated. To suppress this error, handle the LayoutError event and set ThrowException to false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571277/a-windowsformshost-cannot-be-rotated-to-suppress-this-error-handle-the-layoute)

**Layout Considerations for the WindowsFormsHost Element:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744952%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

> Windows Forms controls cannot be rotated or skewed. The WindowsFormsHost element raises the LayoutError event if you apply a skew or rotation transformation. If you do not handle the LayoutError event, an InvalidOperationException is raised.

Comment: But then I wont be able to video stream this TV tuner it's sdk requires an 'Intptr' and WPF controls dont have handles like WinForms controls do, can't get the hwnd of each control its all just in one big WPF window.

Comment: Well, you still cannot rotate a WindowsFormsHost. So you will have to choose between using a Windows Forms control *or* rotating the control. You can't have both as the documentation clearly mentions.

Comment: So should I switch to using directX ;p

Comment: That's another question :) This one is about why you cannot rotate a control.